# Objective-C creating a nested dictionary for AFNetworking parameters

Tags: objective-c, json, encoding, afnetworking

The following code raises an exception, and I can't figure out what is wrong:

```
-(NSDictionary*)prepareParameters:(NSArray*) p_currentParameters
{
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = nil;
    if(self.p_currentParameters.count > 0 )
    {
        parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for(int courseIdx = 0; courseIdx < p_currentParameters.count; courseIdx++)
        {
            CourseDetails* course = p_currentParameters[courseIdx];
            NSMutableDictionary *courseData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            courseData[@"courseIdx"] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:course.id];
            courseData[@"isFavorite"] = @(course.isFavorite);
            courseData[@"isDeleted"] = @(course.isDeleted);
            [parameters setObject:courseData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:courseIdx]];
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}

- (void)sendUserDataOnCourses:(NSArray*) p_currentCourses
{
    @try
    {
        NSString *baseURLString = <API ADDRESS>;
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [parameters setObject:userUniqueId forKey:@"userID"];
        [parameters setObject:[self prepareParameters:p_currentCourses] forKey:@"courses"];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [manager POST:baseURLString
           parameters:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonString, @"request",nil]
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
                  <DO SOME STUFF>
              }
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                  NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Error: %@ Error code: %d timeout counter:%d", error, error.code, timeoutfailure);
              }];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"sendUserDataOnCourses exception: %@",exception);
    }
}
```

The exception occurs on this line: `NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];` and the exception message is: `Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary`.

Comment: `[parameters setObject:courseData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:courseIdx]];`You can't do that. It's said on the doc (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization?language=objc) `All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.` and you are using a `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception is saying, you are trying to insert a non-string key (an object basically) into the dictionary. The JSON serialization method probably doesn't know how to serialize that object since it might not implement a serializable protocol. What I would do is go over every object/value you are trying to insert into the dictionary and see what it is. Then either make them serializable or insert them in a string formation.